# Cannot append uri of more than one image into FormData object

Tags: javascript, form-data

I want to upload image using form data. When I upload one image the image is successfully uploaded but when I append more than one image it will not append. And no data is passed into the server.

```
var data = new FormData();

data.append('imagea',arr[0].uri);//if I append only one image it will get uploaded
data.append('imageb',arr[1].uri);//When I try to append another image it wont append

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'http://192.168.169.188/classifiedad/AdvertisementSvc.svc/NewAdvertisement', true);
xhr.onload = function () {
    console.log(this.responseText);
};
xhr.send(data);
```

Logs[image]

Comment: How is `FormData` object processed at server? Is `arr[1].uri` defined?

Comment: try using `imageList[]` instead of `imagea` and `imageb`.

Comment: The problem is not at the server the, image is not appending in the client in the first place

Comment: I've added the logs. As you can see imagea and imageb have data. I've appended the imageb to the formData object but it wont append.

Comment: Why don't you upload it as Blob, server will treat it as file upload and you'll save 33% of data size transfered

Comment: Ok I Will try it.

Comment: @BiratBadeShrestha What are second and third lines at log at image at Question? Can you reproduce issue at plnkr http://plnkr.co?

Comment: I am firing the request from an android application.

Comment: That should not affect `FomData.append` function, see `Network` browser inspector at http://plnkr.co/edit/ALKvz5Fc2PbZZO26O68Q?p=preview

Comment: The images are coming from another module I don't think It will be possible to recreate the scenario there.

Comment: Is the issue accessing variables or return value from one or more asynchronous functions?, not `FormData.append()` function? `javascript` at Question returns expected result; see `Network` tab at devtools or firebug at http://plnkr.co/edit/ALKvz5Fc2PbZZO26O68Q?p=preview. What is "another module"?

Comment: The problem is FormData.append

Comment: @BiratBadeShrestha _"The problem is FormData.append"_ The  `javascript` at Question returns expected result; see `Network` tab at devtools or firebug at http://plnkr.co/edit/ALKvz5Fc2PbZZO26O68Q?p=preview , select last request, then select `Headers`, then expand `Request Payload`. Both values as appended to `FormData` object and posted by `XMLHttpRequest.send()` call.

Comment: @BiratBadeShrestha See version 2 of plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/ALKvz5Fc2PbZZO26O68Q?p=preview , where values appended to `FormData` are logged at `console` before `send(data)` call.

Comment: I am trying to append data:image/jpeg not data:text/plain

Comment: That should not matter. plnkr is example attempting to reproduce issue, which given only `javascript` at Question, does not reproduce issue described at Question. Both values are appended to `FormData`. Can you include text of `data URI`s which are stored at `arr[0].uri` and `arr[1].uri` at Question?

Comment: Its too long to include.

Comment: You can update and fork plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/ALKvz5Fc2PbZZO26O68Q?p=preview substituting values of `arr[0]uri`, `arr[1].uri` to demonstrate issue. Or, as suggested by @Kaiido, try posting images as `Blob` instead of `data URI`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve